# Vue.JS, можно ли использовать значение зарезервированного атрибута key внутри компонента, созданного с помощью директивы v-for?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, coffeescript

Я разрабатываю приложение на Vue.js. Мне необходимо сделать меню с помощью директивы *v-for*. В компоненте *my_menu* я определяю компонент *my_step*:

```
<my_step
   v-for="(step, index) in steps"
   :key="index"
>
   # тут находится код, который потом будет добавлен в slot
</my_step>
```

В компоненте *my_step* я хочу получить значение *key* (то есть номер шага). Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
<template>
   <div>
      <slot />
   </div>
</template>

<script lang="coffee">
   export default {
      props: {
         key: {
            type: Number
         }
      }
      computed: {
         foo: () ->
            # тут хочу использовать значение key
      }
   }
</script>
```

Но vue выдает ошибку:

> "key" is a reserved attribute and cannot be used as component prop.

Конечно, я могу создать ещё один атрибут, в котором буду передавать компоненту *my_step* номер шага, вот так:

```
<my_step
   v-for="(step, index) in steps"
   :key="index"
   :number_of_step="index"
>
   # тут находится код, который потом будет добавлен в slot
</my_step>
```

Но использование двух свойств с одинаковым значением выглядит нерациональным. Есть ли способ получить значение зарезервированного атрибута *key* внутри компонента *my_step*?

Comment: Так это зарезервированное слово! Вам об этом говорит ошибка.

Comment: Я вижу:) В конце своего вопроса я предложил решение, в котором дублирую зарезервированное значение key. Хотелось бы узнать, нет ли более красивого способа решить проблему, чем использовать подряд два атрибута с одинаковыми значениями.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45852026/vue-how-to-get-a-value-of-a-key-attribute-in-created-element/51089128